# Can i store JSON file locally in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift

I am designing an app where the app has some data to load during launch. Can i store these data in the form of json file inside the app or should i use core data always ? I do not have any server fetch here, so I don't know whether using json is a good option for local storage ..

Comment: You can store your data locally in any format you want.

Comment: thank you .. I thought Apple judge us by the approach we are taking ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can store your data using JSON if you want to. Take a look at the `NSJSONSerialization` class. That will convert your objects back and forth from Foundation classes to JSON files.

However, plists are more convenient for serializing objects in iOS.

There are built in methods for saving and loading Foundation class objects like NSArray and `NSDictionary` as Plists.

If you use the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class you can read and write your data as binary property lists, which are much faster/smaller than the xml format property lists use by default. (See the Xcode docs on `NSPropertyListSerialization` for more information.)